# Программа по математике

Tags: pascal

Необходимо для каждой точки из массива x_lininterpolar[i] найти две точки из первой таблицы, между которыми она попадает, и осуществлять интерполяцию по найденным точкам первой таблицы. Не могу реализовать.
Код программы на pascal:

```
var 
funresults: array [1..15] of real;
x_lininterpolar, y_lininterpolar: array [1..15] of real;
c: integer := 7;
h: real := 0.004;
deltay, y_accuracy: array [1..14] of real;

function f(x: real): real;
 begin 
Result := (c * c * c * cos((x + 10 * c) / c));
end;      
begin 
writeln('Таблица значений функции с вычисленным шагом h');
for i: integer := 1 to 15 do 
begin 
            funresults[i] := f(i * h);
            funresults[i] := Round(funresults[i] * 10000) / 10000;
            WritelnFormat('x = {0} y = {1}', i * h, funresults[i]);
          end;
          writeln('Значения линейной интерполяции:');
          for i: integer := 1 to 15 do 
          begin 
            x_lininterpolar[i] := c + 0.6 * h * i;
            x_lininterpolar[i] := Round(x_lininterpolar[i] * 10000) / 10000;
          end;
          for i: integer := 1 to 14 do 
          begin 
            deltay[i] := f(x_lininterpolar[i + 1]) - f(x_lininterpolar[i]);
          end;
          for i: integer := 1 to 14 do 
          begin 
            y_lininterpolar[i] := f(x_lininterpolar[i]) + deltay[i];
            y_lininterpolar[i] := Round(y_lininterpolar[i] * 10000) / 10000;
            y_accuracy[i] := f(x_lininterpolar[i]);
            y_accuracy[i] := Round(y_accuracy[i] * 10000) / 10000;
          end;
          for i: integer := 1 to 13 do 
          begin 
            WritelnFormat('x = {0} y(приб) = {1} y(точн) = {2}', x_lininterpolar[i], y_lininterpolar[i], y_accuracy[i + 1]);
          end;
          readln();
        end.
```

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается? Найти точки? сделать интерполяцию? Написать прогамму? Мы обязательно должны в вашу програму смотреть, чтобы понимать что вы не можете сделать?

Comment: Зачем вопрос повторять?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Программа на pascal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1057563/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pascal)

Comment: @MBo повтор - дубль. Китайцы на 3-тий день взломали сервер пентагона. На 10000000 раз он согласился что пароль Мау-Дзе-Дун.

Comment: Не получается сделать интерполяцию и написать программу